# Spring MVC Maven Http Status 404

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, pom.xml

I am
getting error I can's solve fix about Http Status 404 Error report

[image]

Spring Frame Work Structure :My Eclipse IDE Project Frame work
[image]

**POM.XML :**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" >
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecs_kpi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ecs_kpi</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

   <!-- Add typical dependencies for a web application -->
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency><groupId>activation
    </groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>ant_lr</groupId>
    <artifactId>ant_lr</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>asm_api</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm_api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>aspect_jrt</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspect_jrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>aspect_jweaver</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspect_jweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>axis</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>cg_lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cg_lib</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>cg_lib-node_p</groupId>
    <artifactId>cg_lib-node_p</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.icu_52.1.0</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.icu_52.1.0</artifactId>
    <version>v201404241930</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.lowagie.text_2.1.7</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.lowagie.text_2.1.7</artifactId>
    <version>v201004222200</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.springsource.javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.jms</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.springsource.javax.portlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.portlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.v20110525</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.springsource.javax.xml.stream</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.xml.stream</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.springsource.org.aopalliance</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.springsource.org.aopalliance</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-bean_utils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-bean_utils</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-cl_i</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-cl_i</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-code_c</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-code_c</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
    <version>0.2</version>
    </dependency>


     <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-file_upload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-file_upload</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-http_client</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-http_client</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-jexl</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-jexl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>



     <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
    <groupId>cos</groupId>
    <artifactId>cos</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
    <groupId>druid</groupId>
    <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>ecskpi-developer</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecskpi-developer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>ezmorph</groupId>
    <artifactId>ezmorph</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>hibernate-commons-annotations</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>hibernate-core</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>hibernate-entitymanager</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
    <groupId>httpclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>httpclient-cache</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient-cache</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>http_core</groupId>
    <artifactId>http_core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>http_core</groupId>
    <artifactId>http_core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>http_mime</groupId>
    <artifactId>http_mime</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>jackson_all</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson_all</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta_oro</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta_oro</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>jav_assist</groupId>
    <artifactId>jav_assist</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.v201103241009</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>jax_b-API</groupId>
    <artifactId>jax_b-API</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
    <groupId>jax_b-API</groupId>
    <artifactId>jax_b-API</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>jax_b-implement</groupId>
    <artifactId>jax_b-implement</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>jax_b-x_jc</groupId>
    <artifactId>jax_b-x_jc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>jax_en-1.1-beta</groupId>
    <artifactId>jax_en-1.1-beta</artifactId>
    <version>7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>jax_rpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>jax_rpc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>j_cl-over-slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>j_cl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>j_common</groupId>
    <artifactId>j_common</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>j_dom</groupId>
    <artifactId>j_dom</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>jet_tison</groupId>
    <artifactId>jet_tison</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>jfree_chart</groupId>
    <artifactId>jfree_chart</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>js</groupId>
    <artifactId>js</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>json-lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
    <version>2.1-jdk15</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>jsr250-api</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>jta</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>jxcell</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxcell</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>jxl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>jxls-core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxls-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>jxls-reader</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxls-reader</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.15</version>
    <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>nocSms</groupId>
    <artifactId>nocSms</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>ojdbc14</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.batik.css_1.6.0</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.batik.css_1.6.0</artifactId>
    <version>v201011041432</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.batik.util_1.6.0</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.batik.util_1.6.0</artifactId>
    <version>v201011041432</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xerces_2.9.0</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.xerces_2.9.0</artifactId>
    <version>v201101211617</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.4.0.v20140611</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.4.0.v201406113</artifactId>
    <version>1043</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.10.0.v20140318</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.10.0.v20140318</artifactId>
    <version>2214</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer_3.2.6</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer_3.2.6</artifactId>
    <version>v201403131814</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda_3.4.3</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda_3.4.3</artifactId>
    <version>v201405301249</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity_1.2.11</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity_1.2.11</artifactId>
    <version>v201401230755</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.emf.common_2.10.0.v20140514</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.common_2.10.0.v20140514</artifactId>
    <version>1158</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change_2.10.0.v20140514</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change_2.10.0.v20140514</artifactId>
    <version>1158</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi_2.10.0.v20140514</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi_2.10.0.v20140514</artifactId>
    <version>1158</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.10.0.v20140514</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.10.0.v20140514</artifactId>
    <version>1158</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.emf_2.6.0.v20140519</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf_2.6.0.v20140519</artifactId>
    <version>0339</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.200.v20130402</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.200.v20130402</artifactId>
    <version>1505</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.5.400.v20140428</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.5.400.v20140428</artifactId>
    <version>1507</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.0.v20140606</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.0.v20140606</artifactId>
    <version>1445</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.w3c.css.sac_1.3.0</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.w3c.css.sac_1.3.0</artifactId>
    <version>v200805290154</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>poi-3.7</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-3.7</artifactId>
    <version>20101029</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>poi-ooxml</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>quartz-all</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>slf4j-api</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>slf4j-log4j12</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>spring-aop</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>spring-aspects</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>spring-beans</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>spring-build-src</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-build-src</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>spring-context</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>spring-context-support</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>spring-core</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>spring-expression</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>spring-instrument</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>spring-instrument-tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>spring-jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>spring-jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>spring-orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>spring-oxm</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>spring-struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-struts</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>spring-test</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>spring-tx</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>spring-web</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>spring-webmvc</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>spring-webmvc-portlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>sqljdbc4</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>standard</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>stax</groupId>
    <artifactId>stax</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>stax-api</groupId>
    <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>Tidy</groupId>
    <artifactId>Tidy</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>tiles-api</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>tiles-core</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>tiles-jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>tiles-servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>tiles-template</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>viewservlets</groupId>
    <artifactId>viewservlets</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>websendMsg</groupId>
    <artifactId>websendMsg</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>wstx-asl</groupId>
    <artifactId>wstx-asl</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>XmlSchema</groupId>
    <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>xml-writer</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-writer</artifactId>
    <version>0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>xom</groupId>
    <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>xpp3_min</groupId>
    <artifactId>xpp3_min</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4c</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>xstream</groupId>
    <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>xstream-benchmark</groupId>
    <artifactId>xstream-benchmark</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>  
   </dependencies>
  <build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3</version>
  <configuration>
  <source>1.7</source>
  <target>1.7</target>
  </configuration>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
   <properties>
        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <project.build.outputDirectory>target/classes</project.build.outputDirectory>
     <!--   Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

    </properties>
</project>
```

Web.XML : I addded welcome list tag but it seems same error showing ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>STS</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Note : Actually I copied POM.xml file from other project source after
I clean and Installed Maven success status .Is it any made I mistaken
during maven installation  ?

Comment: Try to call localhost:8080/ecs_kpi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Comment: For starters your pom is a big mess and tries to include almost every dependency imaginable. You are also using a very old spring boot version? However are you using spring boot because everything else hints at that you are not (or you are at least trying very hard not to).

Comment: Hey , I have tried to pass above snapshot local host URL but still it seems same error .

Comment: check tomcat logs, and see what is the name for the applications that are being deployed(even if is only one).

Answer (score 0):

do you scan the package? I think you should create a simple project use spring mvc 
.by the way  I think you should build step by step .your pom.xml is too big .but it needn't so much.